# What's the best way to put an object in a table with SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I have a program in C# that produces a lot of objects that contain an array of objects. **Is it possible to store "object" arrays inside rows of an SQL table?**

Example:

```
Object1 -> string name, Object2[] o2
Object2 -> int number, string name, Object3[] o3
Object3 -> int type, string condition, bool isDone, byte position
```

I will probably have around 1080 instances of Object1, with ~10 instances of Object2 per Object1, and ~10 instances of Object3 per Object 2 and I need to store this somehow in a usable format.

I'm thinking SQL would be the best solution for this, but I couldn't find anything on storing more complex data like in my given example.

Comment: Can you describe your requirements a bit more? Are you only planning to store and retrieve these from the DB using Object1's properties, or are you just trying to save an object hierarchy? Depending on your querying needs, or lack there of, you may not need a database at all or you may need to decide between a relational or document database.

Comment: @MarcBaumbach I will be heavily querying on this data, but will not have any real need to change it once collected. Basically Object1 is a "day", with an array of events that I will be attempting to find trends in the data between over a 15 year period. The end goal of this project is to use this historical data to predict future events. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store all of the in a class and Serialize it when you want to write it into a binary field and deserialize it after reading it from database.

[This link from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738528(v=vs.100).aspx) might be helpful in your case.
Good luck

Comment: @Ryan Your welcome my friend. I'm happy hearing that.